# K-path sampling transfer function

Tags: transfer-function, sampling, z-transform, switched-capacitor

I'm trying to derive the overall Z-transform for the K-path sampling system shown below from Baker's CMOS Mixed-Signal Circuit Design. I numbered some of the equations that I'll reference. The full document is publicly available from the author [here.](http://cmosedu.com/cmos2/email/k_path.pdf)

I don't think I understand going from equation 3 to equation 4. I understand that \$\frac{V_{o,i}(z)}{V_{in,i}(z)} = H(z)\$, but why is \$\frac{V_{o,i}(z^{1/k})}{V_{in,i}(z^{1/k})} = H(z)\$? Does this follow from equation 1?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equation 4 follows directly from equation 3, since it can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{V_{out}(z^{1/K})}{V_{in}(z^{1/K})}=\frac{\sum_{n=1}^K V_{out,n}(z^{1/K})}{\sum_{n=1}^K V_{in,n}(z^{1/K})}.
$$

Then from equation 2 it follows that \$V_{out,n}(z^{1/K})=H(z)V_{in,n}(z^{1/K})\$, and since all paths are assumed to be equal (at least they are associated to the same transfer function) \$H(z)\$ can be taken out of the summation:
$$
\frac{V_{out}(z^{1/K})}{V_{in}(z^{1/K})}=\frac{H(z)\sum_{n=1}^K V_{in,n}(z^{1/K})}{\sum_{n=1}^K V_{in,n}(z^{1/K})}=\frac{H(z)V_{in}(z^{1/K})}{V_{in}(z^{1/K})}=H(z).
$$

In words, since by definition the individual paths' transfer functions can be expressed as \$H(z)=\frac{V_{out,n}(z^{1/K})}{V_{in,n}(z^{1/K})}\$ and at the output the circuit considers one such \$V_{out,n}(z^{1/K})\$ at the time (due to the non-overlapping clocks \$\phi_n\$), the transfer function that describes the overall circuit is the very same \$H(z)\$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In general, is \$H(z^{1/k})\$ the Z-transform of a downsampled version of the original sequence? From what I've been able to see online the Z-transform of a downsampled function is actually more complicated, but it's close.

Comment: \$H(z^(1/k))\$ means that you are considering samples that are spaced \$T_S/k\$ seconds apart, where your sampling clock has period \$T_S\$. Generally speaking, whether it would result in downsampling or oversampling depends on the signal that goes through that transfer function. In your circuit, I assume that regular sampling is performed, with the only aim of using a multiphase, low-frequency clock to sample a "fast" signal.